# Strange warning

Tags: graphics

I've just got the following warning:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

It is referred, seemingly, to `Lemma2.png`, which is the following image:

[image]

What does it mean and how do I fix it? And what is `libpng`?

More precisely, the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Lemma2.png}
\end{document}
```

generates:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pict@warning@MWEattempt.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
No file pict@warning@MWEattempt.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

<Lemma2.png, id=1, 997.7275pt x 410.53375pt> <use Lemma2.png>
Overfull \hbox (39.88582pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 5--6
[][] 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./Lem
ma2.png>] (./pict@warning@MWEattempt.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2013/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on pict@warning@MWEattempt.pdf (1 page, 513252 bytes).
SyncTeX written on pict@warning@MWEattempt.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on pict@warning@MWEattempt.log.
```

the image being the one above.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @doncherry see edit.

Comment: It is surely related, but the answers there don't explain what `libpng` is nor why this happens, merely referring to "broken" `.png` files causing the warning. Maybe requiring to expand on that term is more of an SO question?

Comment: There's a similar question on SO [libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile) but it doesn't expand any further on the other answers here.

Comment: For more info on `libpng`, [see here](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html). As for `iCCP`: [this should be it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile). [This is sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB).

Comment: Reading that, one figures out the point is there is something wrong with the `sRGB` profile, and that `libpng`, converting it to something, finds the error, recognizes it, corrects it, and then converts. But what _is_ `libpng` converting to? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/) is the currently preferred format for losslessly-encoded bitmap images.  While the basic PNG format is fairly simple, PNG files can contain various [optional metadata](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html#11Ancillary-chunks).  Libpng is the library that most applications use to read PNG files.

One of the pieces of metadata that a PNG file can contain is an [ICC profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile), a bunch of data that says how RGB pixel values are supposed to map to actual colours.  ICC profiles are embedded into PNG files by applications such as Photoshop.

The warning is telling you that libpng has detected that the PNG file contains an incorrect ICC profile.  You can safely ignore this warning — this might result in a slight colour shift (white being slightly yellowish or bluish), but nothing as severe as the typical difference between monitors of different brands.